# Create a subset of data selected on columns in 2d javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Sorry for the basic question and bad lexicon, I am (very) new to javascript. I have an array of data and I would like to create a subset of that data, based on selected columns. The first few rows of my data, for example:

> 0: {ID: 3607, Name: 'Alamo', Funds: 52933955,
> Revenues: 9160109, BAT: 5, …}

> 1: {ID: 3539, Name: 'Alvin', Funds: 6128147,
> Revenues: 964083, BAT: 0, …}

> 2: {ID: 3540, Name: 'Amarillo', Funds: 12450969,
> Revenues: 1716038, BAT: 0, …}

I want to create a new array from columns 0, 1, 2, and 4 (ID, Name, Funds, and BAT). In the code below, `toolData` is the array created from the original dataset (toolData.json), and `tableData` is the array I'm trying to create from the selected data. `selections` contains the column numbers I want to pull into the new array.

```
var getData = () => axios.get('toolData.json')
  .then(res => res.data)
  .then(data => {
    
    var toolData = data;
    console.log(toolData);
    
    var tableData = [];
    var selections = [0,1,2,4];

    for (i=0; i < toolData.length; i++)
    {
      tableData[i] = toolData[i];
      for (j=0; selections.length; j++)
      { 
        k = selections[j],
        tableData[i][j] = toolData[i][k]
      }
    }
    console.log(tableData);
```

This particular code snippet doesn't work at all, I'm assuming I've created an infinite loop somehow. If I comment out `tableData[i] = toolData[i];` then that problem resolves, but the code still doesn't work. `console.log(toolData);` gives me what I'm looking for (the full panel of data), but `console.log(tableData);` gives the error:

```
javascript.js:42 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting '0')
    at javascript.js:42
```

Ultimately I would like the user to be able to choose the columns they want to include in the new array, but before I can figure that puzzle out I need to solve this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems from what you're saying is that every index in the array is an object.. `arr[0][0]==undefined` but `arr[0]['ID']==3607`

```js
function newSubset(arr,dataToSelect){
  //arr is the fetched array, dataToSelect is an array of the keys(like ID,Name...) that you want from the array
  return arr.map(obj=>{
    var toReturn={} //object that would give each desired key for each part in arr
    dataToSelect.forEach(key=>toReturn[key]=obj[key]) //placing wanted keys in toReturn
    return toReturn
  })
}

//usage
var getData = () => axios.get('toolData.json')
  .then(res => res.data)
  .then(data => { 
    var wantedKeys=["ID","Name","Funds","BAT"]
    console.log(newSubset(data,wantedKeys))
    //rest of your code here
```

**LIVE EXAMPLE**

```js
var dataArray=[{ID: 3607, Name: 'Alamo', Funds: 52933955, Revenues: 9160109, BAT: 5},   {ID: 3539, Name: 'Alvin', Funds: 6128147, Revenues: 964083, BAT: 0},   {ID: 3540, Name: 'Amarillo', Funds: 12450969, Revenues: 1716038, BAT: 0}]
function newSubset(arr,dataToSelect){
  //arr is the fetched array, dataToSelect is an array of the keys(like ID,Name...) that you want from the array
  return arr.map(obj=>{
    var toReturn={} //object that would give each desired key for each part in arr
    dataToSelect.forEach(key=>toReturn[key]=obj[key]) //placing wanted keys in toReturn
    return toReturn
  })
}

console.log(newSubset(dataArray,["ID","Name","Funds","BAT"]))
```

Comment: Hey this ended up working perfectly, thank you! I don't understand *why* it works, I need to study the function more closely to get a sense of what it's really doing, but I succesfully implemented into my code so that's half the battle! Thanks again.

Comment: ok.. so the explanation: the array map function takes a function as its argument and spits out a new array based on what the function **returns** for each key.. the function i gave to map returns an object that has the selected keys/columns only

Answer (score 0):

The data is a JSON object. It is not indexed by numbers but rather by names.

It's also recommend to use the built-in `map` function for this.

```js
const tableData = toolData.map(row => ({
    ID: row.ID,
    Name: row.Name,
    Funds: row.Funds,
    BAT: row.BAT
}));
```

If you want the new `toolData` array to contain arrays instead of objects, you can instead do:

```js
const tableData = toolData.map(row => [
    row.ID,
    row.Name,
    row.Funds,
    row.BAT
]);
```

Comment: Hey sorry I can't give this an upvote because I'm too new, but it worked perfectly, thank you! I chose the other answer as The Answer only because the function works perfectly with the next stage of my project, which is allowing the user to make the column selections themselves. It was helpful to have this simpler solution spelled out though, since it's easier to see exactly what's happening.